# Why spark streaming is slow?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I used spark streaming example program from github repository and tries with kafka and custom receiver. In both I am getting output after 20-30 seconds. In custom receiver code, I am getting data instantly but output takes 20-30 seconds. I am running this code on single node.

Am I doing something wrong or is there optimization, I need to perform or is it because I am running on single node.

If anybody can guide me for this would a great help.

I used the code from the spark repository, here is the code :

```
import scala.Tuple2;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.StorageLevels;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.Duration;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaPairDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaReceiverInputDStream;
import org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Counts words in UTF8 encoded, '\n' delimited text received from the network every second.
 * Usage: JavaNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>
 *   <hostname> and <port> describe the TCP server that Spark Streaming would connect to receive       data.
 *
 * To run this on your local machine, you need to first run a Netcat server
 *    `$ nc -lk 9999`
 * and then run the example
 *    `$ bin/run-example org.apache.spark.examples.streaming.JavaNetworkWordCount localhost 9999`
 */
 public final class JavaNetworkWordCount {
    private static final Pattern SPACE = Pattern.compile(" ");

public static void main(String[] args) {
  if (args.length < 2) {
    System.err.println("Usage: JavaNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>");
    System.exit(1);
}

StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels();

// Create the context with a 1 second batch size
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf,  new Duration(1000));

// Create a JavaReceiverInputDStream on target ip:port and count the
// words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
// Note that no duplication in storage level only for running locally.
// Replication necessary in distributed scenario for fault tolerance.
JavaReceiverInputDStream<String> lines = ssc.socketTextStream(
        args[0], Integer.parseInt(args[1]), StorageLevels.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER);
JavaDStream<String> words = lines.flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public Iterable<String> call(String x) {
    return Lists.newArrayList(SPACE.split(x));
  }
});
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> wordCounts = words.mapToPair(
  new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String s) {
      return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(s, 1);
    }
  }).reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
      return i1 + i2;
    }
  });

wordCounts.print();
ssc.start();
ssc.awaitTermination();
}
}
```

Comment: This question needs more detail, how much data, what kind of operations are you doing. Also FYI there is basically no point of running spark on a single node

Comment: I am just testing spark streaming. I used wordcount program. Because I want to learn first and after that, create cluster and run the main complex task on cluster.

Comment: What is your window size, if it's > 20 seconds, it would make sense for results to start coming after 20-30 seconds and then hopefully faster after that, also have you implemented the aggregate and inverse aggregate functions for wordcount

Comment: i havn't defined window size. and what is aggregate and inverse aggregate?

Comment: I think this would be easier to answer if you actually posted the code you are running

Comment: Code from this link : [link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaNetworkWordCount.java)

Comment: exactly that code? unmodified? It's always better to post the code than to link to it - that also leaves a reference to future readers looking for a similar answer.

Comment: I added the code in post. I used unmodified code.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anywhere the master configuration. When you say you are running on one node, I guess you mean "local" mode and not a standalone single node.
If that's the case local by default uses a single thread which will be used by the received and starve the executor.

Try changing new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount"); to
new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount").setMaster("local[4]");

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have meant `local[*]` master, because otherwise program will not start. I also hope that you did not set `local[1]` because that would also be an error for local mode. (Spark will not be able to execute normally). See Gonzalo's answer above.

I also presume you have more or less modern hardware.

I have just actually run this simple example and I do not experience any delays or other problems with sending input via `nc` like javadoc suggests.

As far as I can see, this code does not have any issues with performance: trivial operations, nothing to improve. From both Java perspective and Spark one. RDD caching would not help here since there are no repetitive calculations (RDD is only printed once).

You mentioned Kafka, but code does not reference it. If it is still actual, please post relevant code as well.

Otherwise, there is no enough evidence to call Spark streaming slow :).